# Match The First And Last Character Of An Excel Spreadsheet Cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, substring

I have a spreadsheet with addresses.  Sometimes, those addresses are encapsulated in double-quotes.  I created a formula that I thought would work, but it isn't removing the double-quotes.  Obviously, it isn't matching the logic.

Sample Data:

```
"194 Notch Ln."
```

My formula:

```
=IF(AND(RIGHT(A1)=""", LEFT(A1)="""), MID(A1, 1, LEN(A1)-1), A1)
```

Is there an issue with my formula?  Excel didn't throw up any errors.  I read that enclosing a double-quote in double-quotes would escape it (I'm using to `"\""` in PHP).

Comment: Wouldn't `SUBSTITUTE` work much better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should double your quotes *within* the quotes.  So instead of `"""`, use `""""`.

Also, Excel strings are one-based, so to grab the second character through the next-to-last character, do this:

```
=IF(AND(RIGHT(A1)="""", LEFT(A1)=""""), MID(A1, 2, LEN(A1)-2), A1)
```

You need to subtract 2 from the length of the string to account for the removed quotes.

And as @jbarker2160 pointed out, `SUBSTITUTE` may work better for this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"""","")
```

Comment: I still don't get the double-quote idea, but the LEN()-2 makes sense.  I was thinking it was number of characters from the right and not a number of characters from the left.

Comment: C and JavaScript use escape sequences to allow you to enter quotes within quotes.  You could do "\"" in those languages instead of """".  They also allow you to use single quotes to encompass a string with double quotes, like '"'.  Microsoft's double-quote syntax always seemed odd to me.

Answer (score 1):

Double Double quote, Use: '=IF(AND(RIGHT(A1,1)="""",LEFT(A1,1)="""")=TRUE,MID(A1, 2, LEN(A1)-2),A1)'.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just use wild card characters as so:

```
 =IF(COUNTIF(H10,"*"&"Notch"&"*"),1,0)
```

You could replace "Notch" with a cell reference. "COUNTIF" will correctly evaluate the wildcards but "IF" by itself doesn't.
This avoids having to remove the quotes, you could use the data as is depending on what you're trying to do downstream.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Of course, that will only work with the sample address and this log contains many addresses that wouldn't match.